# Regex to extract date and specific string

Tags: python, regex

I have a a filename below and I want to extract `year` and `_TEXT` part.

fle_2019-11-17A17-21-09.01(_TEXT).txt

I am able to do this using two regex and then join the results.

`(?<=\_)(\d{4})(?=\-)`
This gives me `year`

`(?<=\()(.*)(?=\))` This gives me `_TEXT`

Is there a way to get this from a single expression?

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: Python. Sorry forgot to mention previously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use 2 capturing groups. Depending on what you would allow to match before the first underscore, you could for example use a character class to match word characters without an underscore `[^\W_]+`

```
^[^\W_]+_(\d{4})-[\w.-]+\(([^)]+)\)\.\w+$
```

In parts

- `^` Start of string
- `[^\W_]+` Match 1+ word chars except `_`
- `_` Match the `_`
- `(\d{4})` Capture **group 1**, match 1+ digits
- `-[\w.-]+` Match `-` and 1+ word chars, `.` or `-` (extend the character class with what you would allow to match
- `\(` Match `(`

  - `([^)]+)` Capture **group 2**, match 1+ times any char except `)`
- `\)` Match `)`
- `\.\w+` Match a `.` and 1+ word chars
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8IFbRE/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/jgH3Pt)

For example

```
import re

regex = r"^[^\W_]+_(\d{4})-[\w.-]+\(([^)]+)\)\.\w+$"
test_str = "fle_2019-11-17A17-21-09.01(_TEXT).txt"
print(re.findall(regex, test_str))
```

Output

```
[('2019', '_TEXT')]
```

Comment: This is not a complete answer, because it fails to provide any actual Python code.

Answer (score 1):

In the interest of simplicity, we could just try using `re.findall` with an alternation which captures either a 4 digit year or a file name:

```
file = "fle_2019-11-17A17-21-09.01(_TEXT).txt"
parts = re.findall(r'\d{4}(?=-\d{2})|(?<=\().*?(?=\))', file)
print(parts)
```

This prints:

```
['2019', '_TEXT']
```

I like this approach because the output already yields separate logical values for the year and file name.

Comment: @Thefourthbird Thanks for casting doubt on my answer.

Comment: It is not meant to cast doubt on the answer, but perhaps something to mention. I will remove the comment.

Comment: I agree with you, but I am assuming the OP has a bunch of files all with the same format in a folder somewhere (in a list in Python), and it wants to extract the year and name features.  My answer does not attempt any validation.